# Play Framework Activator Error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

Cannot Run Activator command after new Project Creation

```
raghul@raghul-Inspiron-N4010:~/Documents/activator-dist-1.3.5/UZAdmin$ activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/raghul/Documents/activator-dist-1.3.5/UZAdmin/project
/home/raghul/Documents/activator-dist-1.3.5/UZAdmin/build.sbt:17: error: not found: value routesGenerator
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

My `build.sbt` file :

```
name := """UZAdmin""" 

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT" 

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc, cache, javaWs ) 

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the 
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Comment: Can you show us your `build.sbt` file ?

Comment: name := """UZAdmin"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

Answer (score 3):

Your `build.sbt` is missing an import:

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys._

name := """UZAdmin""" 

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT" 

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc, cache, javaWs ) 

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the 
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```